# Error when opening the exe file which is made from darkflow

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, darkflow

I am using darkflow for custom object detection it is working perfectly fine and it is running perfectly through anaconda prompt. I made the exe using pyinstaller, So when I was running the exe it is showing the above error. Can anyone help me to get rid of this? I tried installing darkflow globally also but it didn't work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from darkflow.net.build import TFNet
  File "c:\users\camfyvision\anaconda3\envs\darkflow\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "darkflow\net\build.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .framework import create_framework
  File "c:\users\camfyvision\anaconda3\envs\darkflow\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "darkflow\net\framework.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import yolo
  File "c:\users\camfyvision\anaconda3\envs\darkflow\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "darkflow\net\yolo\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import predict
  File "c:\users\camfyvision\anaconda3\envs\darkflow\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "darkflow\net\yolo\predict.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ...cython_utils.cy_yolo_findboxes import yolo_box_constructor
  File "c:\users\camfyvision\anaconda3\envs\darkflow\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
  File "darkflow\cython_utils\cy_yolo_findboxes.pyx", line 1, in init darkflow.cython_utils.cy_yolo_findboxes
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'darkflow.cython_utils.nms'
```

This is the error I got when I did drag and drop of the exe into propmt and also I am providing below the corresponding information I got regarding the error when I was making the exe using pyinstaller.

136360 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\CamfyVision\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\darkflow.cython_utils.cy_yolo_findboxes.pyd
136361 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
136413 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\CamfyVision\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\darkflow.cython_utils.cy_yolo2_findboxes.pyd
136414 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033

Comment: Please don't post text as images, update your question including the error as text.

Comment: It is showing no module called darkflow.cython.utils, but this error is coming only through exe, no issue while running the python file.

Comment: Hi Luis, I have updated my error as text. Please go through it and I am expecting your valuable reply.

Comment: I think some of your requirements are not installed properly. Might not only be dark flow. In your case, I dont know what's the fastest way to solve the problem. The last time I converted my py file to exe., I faced similar issues. What i did was reinstall python, ensure that ONLY SCRIPTS NEEDED are installed. Then i did the same converting to exe procedure. It works right after.

Comment: Besides I think it's easier to convert using this module, https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/. You may try it out.

Comment: Hi Sin, Thanks for your response, I have tried it but it didn't work. It looks like a cython issue. I have googled it but it's quite confusing how to resolve the issue. Do you have aby idea.

Comment: In some git hub issues, people are saying to modify the spec file accordingly for Cython but I don't what kind of modification it should be.

Comment: Can anyone help me from the darkflow side.?? It would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the valuable comment. However I solved the issue by --hidden-import darkflow.cython_utils.nms script.py